# AWS SSM parameter issue with special characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am new to AWS. I am working on integrating SSM parameters to store database passwords and use the same at the time of cloud formation.

We observed a issue with SSM Parameters value having special characters at the beginning of the string.

For example, if the password is Test@123, its working fine. But if the password is @Test!123 then it’s not working.

Is there any work around for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by enclosing the password beginning with special characters in double quotes. For example

```
@Test!123
```

Comment: where are the double quotes exactly...? i ran into the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think I found the solution to my problem. I have a password like this "complicated!word+=!here!help+", and this is how I am able to escape it:

```
aws ssm put-parameter --name /config/my-api_alpha/my-db.jdbc.password --value “complicated\!word+=\!here\!help+” --type SecureString --key-id  arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:1234567890:key/this-is-a-kms-keyId
```

The double quotes are optional; this produces the same result:

```
aws ssm put-parameter --name /config/my-api_alpha/my-db.jdbc.password --value complicated\!word+=\!here\!help+ --type SecureString --key-id  arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:1234567890:key/this-is-a-kms-keyId
```